# Tesseract read just numbers from text

Tags: ocr, tesseract, javacv

How can I get the just the numeric values from image containing english text. I am using tesseract engine .

this is the code :

```
    public static String tesseractOCR(String imgPath, Rectangle rect) {
    File imageFile = new File(imgPath);
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
    // Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = instance.doOCR(imageFile, rect);//, new Rectangle(50, 128, 405 - 50, 228 - 128)
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract will grabb all the characters from image including alphabets,numbers,punctuation symbols etc.So, you need to remove the non-numeric values from the extracted text explicitly.You can use regular expressions for that.